# kill a process by name if running longer than 24 hours

Tags: command-line

I'm currently trying to kill any program that has run over 48 hours with the name "cool-program"

I understand that if I run

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,comm,etime | grep -i  cool-program | grep -v grep
```

it gives me a list of the programs, now I'm not sure how to further filter this to only programs that have been running over a day

given the comments to have it print out a list of the `pid` of cool program I'm using but when I try and pipe this to `kill` it does not kill the programs

```
ps -eo bsdstart,pid,comm | grep -i ffmpeg | grep -v '^[ 0-9]' | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Comment: Couldn't you add stime which I think means start time where anything over 1 day will show the Month name at the beginning? Then you can filter down by excluding the lines that start with numbers. Example: `ps -eo stime,pid,cmd | grep -i cool-program | grep -v '^[0-9]'`

Comment: wouldn't that show programs less than a day old when UTC changes to new day?

Comment: I guess you could try `bsdstart` where it states:  `time the command started.  If the process was started less than 24 hours ago, the output format is " HH:MM", else it is " Mmm:SS" (where Mmm is the three letters of the month).  See also lstart, start, start_time, and stime.`

Comment: `ps -eo bsdstart,pid,cmd | grep -i cool-porgram | grep -v '^[ 0-9]'`

Comment: if you want to make your last comment a answer I will accept as that did it, at least printing out the process name, but when I try and pipe it into kill it breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the man page for `ps` it states if you use `bsdstart` it will show the time the command started:

```
   bsdstart    START     time the command started.  If the process was
                         started less than 24 hours ago, the output format
                         is " HH:MM", else it is " Mmm:SS" (where Mmm is
                         the three letters of the month).  See also
                         lstart, start, start_time, and stime.
```

Then you can use a combined command to pull the date, pid, and the command running and using grep to exclude `-v` the lines that start with numbers or spaces then numbers like so:

```
ps -eo bsdstart,pid,cmd | grep -i cool-porgram | grep -v '^[ 0-9]'
```

To kill them the command would be:

```
sudo kill $(ps -eo bsdstart,pid,cmd | grep -i cool-porgram | grep -v '^[ 0-9]' | awk '{print $3}')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: edited the question, this prints out the `pid` but when piped into kill does not kill the list of programs

Comment: @nadermx You might need to sudo the command.